# Converting from String to Long after sending a message using UDP unicast

Tags: java, serialization, type-conversion, udp, deserialization

I am sending a message using UDP unicast,

First of all I have a long variable that I convert to a String and then y serialize:

```
        timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis(); // Current time in miliseconds
        String a=Long.toString(timeStamp);
        millisBytes=a.getBytes();
        dp=new DatagramPacket(millisBytes,millisBytes.length,ip,3000);
        ds.send(dp); // Send the datagram
```

I recibe this package in another aplication, the recibed data is a byte array, y convert this to a string and then y use Long.parseLong() (I also tryed Long.valueOf()):

```
        buf=new byte[length];
        DatagramPacket dp=new DatagramPacket(buf, length);
        ds.receive(dp);
        millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        milisInicial=Long.parseLong(new String(dp.getData()));
```

The error is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1521624607119"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
at com.comunytek.roundTrip.ServidorRoundTrip.main(ServidorRoundTrip.java:38)
```

1521624607119 is a number so, any Idea why this could happen?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it so far. Serializing and parsing a `long` works perfectly. Can you please post what happens at `ServidorRoundTrip.java:38` ? I.e. how does that invoke `Long.parseLong` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Long.parseLong(new String(dp.getData()));
```

Usual problem. You are ignoring the length of the received datagram. Try this:

```
Long.parseLong(new String(dp.getData(),0,dp.getLength()));
```

Comment: With Long.parseLong(new String(dp.getData(),dp.getOffset(),dp.getLength())); is working fine, thank you a lot!

Comment: @JimGarrison If you aren't sure that the original `DatagramPacket` wasn't constructed with a non-zero offset, sure. In this case, it isn't necessary. The offset won't change as a result of `receive()`.

Comment: @JimGarrison The contract is that if the offset isn't specified, by omission of the parameter, it is zero. See the Javadoc. The `receive()` method is not entitled to place data anywhere outside the constraints of `(byte[] buffer, int offset, int length)`.